# Piping find to find

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to pipe a find result to a new find. What I have is:

```
find . -iname "2010-06*" -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -0 find '{}' -iname "*.jpg"
```

Expected result: Second find receives a list of folders starting with 2010-06, second find returns a list of jpg's contained within those folders.

Actual result: "find: ./2010-06 New York\n: unknown option"

Oh darn. I have a feeling it concerns the format of the output that the second find receives as input, but my only idea was to suffix -print0 to first find, with no change whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need 2 things. `-print0`, and more importantly `-I{}` on xargs, otherwise the `{}` doesn't do anything.

```
find . -iname "2010-06*" -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} find '{}' -iname '*.jpg'
```

Comment: From `man find`: "-and is assumed where the operator is omitted." Thus order doesn't matter since they're all evaluated and must all be true.

Comment: Also, "Fantastic. This works as expected." should be a clue that... you know... it works... as expected :P

Comment: Useless use of xargs. Much too long and overcomplicated for such a simple task.

Comment: It's friggin bash, since when is it ever elegant? You want elegant, use python.

Answer (score 7):

Useless use of xargs.

```
find 2010-06* -iname "*.jpg"
```

At least Gnu-find accepts multiple paths to search in. -maxdepth and type -d is implicitly assumed.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
find . -iwholename "./2010-06*/*.jpg
```

etc?

Comment: You must include the leading "./" in the value given to the option.

Comment: It's `-iwholename`, not `-iwholepath`

Comment: Much more elegant solution, you are right. Though what I did not thoroughly explain was, that I am interested in making pipes work, and not specifically this find problem. Thanks though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Although you did say that you specifically want this find + pipe problem to work, its inefficient to fork an extra `find` command. Since you are specifying -maxdepth as 1, you are not traversing subdirectories. So just use a `for` loop with shell expansion.

```
for file in *2010-06*/*.jpg
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

If you want to find all jpg files inside each 2010-06* folders recursively, there is also no need to use multiple `finds` or `xargs`

```
for directory in 2010-06*/
do
   find $directory -iname "*.jpg" -type f
done
```

Or just

`find 2006-06* -type f -iname "*.jpg"`

Or even better, if you have bash 4 and above

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for file in 2010-06*/**/*.jpg
do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: This doesn't match the functionality. The -maxdepth 1 eliminates ./abc/2010-06/def/ghi.jpg, but not ./2010-06/def/ghi.jpg.

Comment: I suggest you make a test for yourself and find out. See the find man page for what maxdepth is.

Comment: I suggest you try this test case: `mkdir -p 2010-06/def; touch 2010-06/def/ghi.jpg; for file in *2010-06*/*.jpg; do echo "$file"; done` Output: `bash: no match: *2010-06*/*.jpg` (with bash's glob failing turned on)

Comment: Notice the -maxdepth in both the question and accepted answer only applies to the 2010-06 directory name, *not* the final filename.

Comment: The fact that maxdepth 1 is turned on means he wants to find those 2006 directories and the present working directory. Now, i don't know whether if OP wants to traverse those 2006 directories after that, because he uses xargs and find again (traversing). If that is the case, why don't he just use one find statement? My first example assumes he is not going to traverse at all, so that's why your argument will not apply to my first case.